# Scala generic way to split on line breaks in string

Tags: string, scala, input, split, line-breaks

I'm looking for a clean way to split on line breaks in a string in Scala, regardless of if the line break is CR and/or LF. I've been using `.split` with a basic regex, but it seems ugly and strikes me as something a standard library would naturally encapsulate for system-agnostic code-- is there a standard library function for this?

Thanks in advance!

edit:

I like my code to be system-agnostic, as that one of the great selling points of the JVM. Having my code be aware of different OS conventions in a hardcoded string-literal regex seems to (very slightly) break that. It seems like something that should naturally be abstracted by the feature-rich Scala standard library, and I was just curious to see if a built-in method existed.

Comment: "prone to typos over time"? Eh? you write it once, as a method.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I just meant it seemed like a natural thing for the standard library to encapsulate, but all the solutions I found by searching seemed to be regex-based.

Comment: FWIW, "s.split("""\R""")` is independent of the OS, and works exactly the same way on all systems. It is also a bit different from what I suggested in my answer, because it allows  a few other possibilities for "line-end" (like form-feed, line-tabulation, and some unicode additions, like "next line" etc.).
So, it's not so much the operating system that's an issue here, as it is the actual convention that you want to follow.

Comment: I really don't understand how this can be downvoted and the answer upvoted. What's wrong with SO? Also, I understood "prone to typos", i.e., bugs you uncover over time b/c minor typo or mistake. Give me a bullet-proof library solution any time. Though I'm pretty sure there are SO answers recommending getLines, if one could only find them.

Comment: @Dima I wasn't aware of the """\R""" regex class-- that's definitely good to know, thanks. I was using the regex """\r|\n|\r\n""", and didn't like how it was dependent on OS convention.

Comment: @Nathan what you were using isn't OS dependent either. It works the same way on any OS (and also the same way my answer works).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scala.io.Source.fromString(string).getLines.toList` perhaps?